# Error: display acronyms in chapters name

Tags: chapters, acronyms

I am faced with a problem. I would like to display the chapter's name in the header which contains an acronym. The error is the following one:

> Package glossaries Error: Glossary entry `AC:CSR' has not been defined.

[image]

However, I can see my printed list of acronyms in my document.
When I remove my acronym in the chapter name. I don't have the error anymore.

[image]

---

Here my code:

**Main File:**

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[LAE,LFE,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek,main=english]{babel}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{gensymb}    % Symbole °
\usepackage{amsmath}    % Pour encadrer les équations
\usepackage{cancel}     % Pour barrer des termes dans les équations
\usepackage[breaklinks,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{palatino}   % Police
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   % Pour faire une en-tête
\usepackage{color}      % Pour les tableaux en couleur
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}   % Pour les tableaux en couleur
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{makecell}

\title{Internship Report - V2}
\author{Dylan \textsc{Chevalier}}
\date{June 2022}

\input{Others/acronyms}
\addbibresource{Others/References.bib}

\begin{document}

\appendix

\chapter{\acrfull{ac:csr}}
\label{ap:csr}
\input{Chapters/Appendices/CSR/csr}

\end{document}
```

**Class File:**

```
\ProvidesClass{Internship_Report}[2022/06/02 - Internship Report]

\LoadClass[11pt,twoside]{report}

\RequirePackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage[toc,acronym]{glossaries}
\RequirePackage{caption}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[titles]{tocloft}

\RequirePackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr, titlesec}
\RequirePackage{lastpage}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage{makeidx}
\RequirePackage{rotating}
\RequirePackage{pifont}
\RequirePackage{listings}
\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage{xifthen}
\RequirePackage{pdfpages}
\RequirePackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage[strict]{changepage}
\RequirePackage{csquotes}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Geometry 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage[a4paper,top=3.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,outer=1in,inner=1.5in]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{showframe}

\setlength{\headheight}{13.59999pt}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Chapter / Section / Appendix 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{fmtcount}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{-23\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \thispagestyle{fancy} \huge\bfseries \thechapter.\space  % Change the size of the chapter title
        %\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak %\Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
  
\newcommand\appendix@chapter[1]{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
    \refstepcounter{chapter}%
    \def\app@ct{Appendix \@Alph\c@chapter: #1}
    \orig@chapter*{\thispagestyle{fancy}\vspace*{-70\p@} \huge\bfseries \app@ct}      % Change the size of the chapter title
    \markboth{\MakeUppercase{\app@ct}}{\MakeUppercase{\app@ct}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\normalsize\bfseries\app@ct}%
}
\let\orig@chapter\chapter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{\let\chapter\appendix@chapter}

\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead} {\vskip 40}{\vskip 20}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vskip 40}{\vskip 20}{}{}



\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Hearder / Footer
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LE]{}
\fancyfoot[RO]{}
\fancyfoot[LO]{}
\fancyheadoffset{0cm}

\fancypagestyle{PageNum}{%
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[RE]{}
    \fancyhead[LO]{}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[LE]{}
    \fancyfoot[RO]{}
    \fancyfoot[LO]{}
    \fancyheadoffset{0cm}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\newcommand{\BlankPageNum}{
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{PageNum}
    \mbox{}
    \newpage
}

\newcommand{\BlankPage}{
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \mbox{}
    \newpage
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Contents / Figures / Tables / Bibliography Acronyms names
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\renewcommand\contentsname{\vspace{-2.55cm} \centering \huge\bfseries Table of Contents}
\renewcommand\listfigurename{\vspace{-2.55cm} \centering \huge\bfseries List of Figures}
\renewcommand\listtablename{\vspace{-2.55cm} \centering \huge\bfseries List of Tables}
\renewcommand\bibname{\centering \huge\bfseries Bibliography}
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: please make your example smaller and so that it can be tested: it shouldn't load local files and unnecessary packages.

Comment: Yes you're right. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commands inside sectioning commands must be robust.

The standard approach is to add `\protect` before it.
`\chapter{\protect\acrfull{ac:csr}}` doesn't work here (I don't know why), but `\chapter{\csr}` where `\csr` is defined as robust does.

[image: x]

(using a simplified preamble)

```
\documentclass{report}

\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage[toc,acronym]{glossaries}

\RequirePackage[a4paper,top=3.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,outer=1in,inner=1.5in]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{showframe}

\setlength{\headheight}{13.59999pt}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{-23\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \thispagestyle{fancy} \huge\bfseries \thechapter.\space  % Change the size of the chapter title
        %\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \fi
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak %\Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 40\p@
}}

\newcommand\appendix@chapter[1]{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
    \refstepcounter{chapter}%
    \def\app@ct{Appendix \@Alph\c@chapter: #1}
    \orig@chapter*{\thispagestyle{fancy}\vspace*{-70\p@} \huge\bfseries \app@ct}      % Change the size of the chapter title
    \markboth{\MakeUppercase{\app@ct}}{\MakeUppercase{\app@ct}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\normalsize\bfseries\app@ct}%
}
\let\orig@chapter\chapter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{\let\chapter\appendix@chapter}

\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead} {\vskip 40}{\vskip 20}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vskip 40}{\vskip 20}{}{}

\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Hearder / Footer
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LE]{}
\fancyfoot[RO]{}
\fancyfoot[LO]{}
\fancyheadoffset{0cm}


\newacronym[type=\glsdefaulttype]{ac:csr}{CSR}{Corporate Social Responsabity} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<   

\begin{document}
    
    \appendix   
    \DeclareRobustCommand{\csr}{\acrfull{ac:csr}} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<        
    \chapter{\csr}      

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! It works very well !